# How to highlight element in protractor at run time

Tags: javascript, protractor

In my **protractor** framework, I would like to highlight the found element in UI.
I tried with below code and it is working fine if I use `locators(id,name,className,linkText,xpath)`. When I am using `locators (buttonText,repeater,model,binding)` below code is not working and throwing "
**Invalid locator**" error.

Instead of "`browser.driver.findElement(locator);`" this if I use "`element(locator);`" code is not working and throwing

> "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory"

Node version---2.15.1

Protractor version ---3.2.2

How I am calling the function:-

`highlightElement(by.linkText('log In'));`---working fine

`highlightElement(by.buttonText('Place order'));`-- Throwing error

```
highlightElement = function(locator){
                    console.log("highlight--");

                    console.log("locator---:"+locator);
                    var ele = browser.driver.findElement(locator);

                    return browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",ele, "color: Red; border: 2px solid red;").
                        then(function(resp){
                        browser.sleep(2000);
                        return ele;
                    },function(err){
                        console.log("error is :"+err);
                    });


                };
```

Please help me is there any other way to highlight the element in protractor.

Regards,

Deepak Kumar Susarla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close.  All those locators that your function **is working** for are inherited from webDriver directly.  This list includes  - 
`className, css, id, linkTest, js, name, partialLinkText, tagName, and xpath`;

The others that **are not working** are Protractor's prototypal inheritance.  This list includes - `addLocator, binding, exactBinding, model, buttonText, partialButtonText, repeater, exactRepeater, cssContainingText, options, and deepCss`.

Similarly - the call in your function `findElement` is inherited from webDriver.  So you are essentially calling `findElement(by.buttonText())` which is not supported (protractor's `element(by.buttonText())` would work).

As far as your code, I modified a few things and it seems to work for me:

```
highlightElement = function(el){
  console.log("highlight--");

  console.log("locator---:"+el.locator());

  return browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",el.getWebElement(), "color: Red; border: 2px solid red;").
  then(function(resp){
    browser.sleep(2000);
    return el;
  },function(err){
    console.log("error is :"+err);
  });
};
```

note the **el.locator()**, **el.getWebElement()**, and instead of declaring the element within the function `var ele = browser.driver.findElement(locator);` you can simply pass it the element as an argument.  To give a reference, here's my example code:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('changes the color', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    var ely = element(by.model('first')); // using model
    highlightElement(ely); // works with model
    browser.sleep(5000); // just to see the header change color
    expect(ely.getAttribute('style')).toContain('color: red');
  });
});
```

source: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api

Comment: @DeepakKumarSusarla no problem!  if it solved your issue please consider accepting my answer!

Comment: Can you explain to me where I should put this function inside my e2e folder? Right inside the e2e-spec.ts?

Comment: @David, you can keep this function in common methods file(if you have), and from there you can call this function.